# Block all websites except Kahn academy

Tags: internet, hosts, youtube

I am trying to set up a ubuntu user so that they can access the Kahnacademy instructional website, but not anything else.  In particular, I want to block youtube.
[There are instructions here](https://kb.k12usa.com/Knowledgebase/Allow-Khan-Academy-Videos-While-Keeping-Youtube-Blocked) but I cannot get them to work.
Basically, I can either block youtube with the /etc/hosts file, but then the videos don't play, or else the videos play and youtube is unblocked.
Is there a simple way to allow only traffic coming from the Kahnacademy website to access youtube?

Comment: Is there a content filter or anything else available that would be better suited to the task?

Comment: I'd much rather not use a content filter, as I also would like to avoid watching 10000 hours of supposedly age-appropriate cartoons.

Comment: The instructions you liked to didn't tell you to block YouTube.com before enabling KhanAcademy.org but rely on that; have you done that?

Comment: If I block youtube with /etc/hosts, no videos would play.  (Which makes sense to me, as it seems that KhanAcademy makes a fairly standard use of youtube, which is correctly intercepted.)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC blocking sites in /etc/hosts only overrides the machine's DNS lookup, instead of actually blocking the connections, so kids could likely still get to youtube by going to the IP in the address bar directly

I'd use the iptables firewall to do this, so your rule chain would look something like:

```
iptables --append OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

to make already established connections work.

Then, for the IP of the main khan academy site and those of each of the sites needing whitelisted mentioned in that guide (which can be found using, for example, `dig +short youtube-nocookie.com` from `dnsutils`,)

```
iptables --append OUTPUT --destination [IP of site] -j ACCEPT
```

Which will allow any outgoing connections to those sites

Then to DROP all outgoing connection requests from this user that haven't been accepted in the previous rules,

```
iptables --append OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner [Ubuntu-Username] -j DROP
```

then save/set configuration

```
iptables-save
```

So the way that works is

```
(UbuntuUser requests connection, sending output packet)
=> (if packet is part of an ongoing relationship, Accept (send) it)
=> (if packet destination is a khanacademy site, Accept it) 
=> (if packet is from this user, and hasn't been accepted already, drop it)
```

The downside is that if the IP of any of those sites you need to whitelist changes, you'll have to reconfigure the iptables rules, and to be able to use this way you need to have admin rights to the machine, but it gives you control over network packets at the kernel-level which is harder for someone to figure a way around

You'd probably want to do something similar to the INPUT chain too if it's not been handled already, but the above should (in theory, I haven't tried it in practice) achieve what you need

That guide may be out of date too, the first of those whitelist sites doesn't appear to be online

Comment: Thank you for this.  Do you have any idea if doing this (which would take some work) would enable the videos from Kahnacademy?  I am worried those would also be blocked, but I am not sure.

Comment: I don't know how the KA site works, but if that guide is to be trusted it should do, iptables is sort of the de facto network filtering system for Linux, but I'd check with IT to see if they have a preferred way first. You'd have to add a version of the second rule for each of those sites (kasandbox, kastatic, etc,) listed in the guide, but the guide itself may be out of date, or KA may have changed their code in the last 2 years. If it doesn't work and you need to reset it, you can do that with `iptables -F OUTPUT`. It looks however that the videos will be on youtube-nocookie, accepted step 2